# How do I show an old FB app review submission?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.2

Last year we submitted a Facebook app for review and our use of user_likes was approved as an item. I didn't keep a record of the text I used to describe how we use user_likes. Now I need to submit a very similar app for a different customer. Is there a way to dig up the old approval form contents?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a Facebook customer support issue.

Comment: Facebook doesn't have a place to submit this kind of stuff, they point people at Stackoverflow for everything except bugs...

Comment: Facebook directs people to [so] for help with *technical* issues. Locating a field of text that was submitted to Facebook as part of their developers console is not a technical issue - there is no programming/IT related questions here - you are asking about Facebook usage.

Comment: I agree though - FB really doesn't have a place to ask these types of questions. Unfortunately, the lack of their support does not validate asking off-topic questions on [so].

Comment: Yeah okay, I suppose that's fair enough in the context of Stack Overflow, although it's a useful resource if the question gets answered....

Comment: Useful - yes. Useful on a technical/programming level (which is what [so] is all about) - I don't think so.

Answer (score 1):

You should ask the Facebook crew about that. However, I believe that should not be interesting. You should fill the values according to your best understanding of the features, especially, because some features might have been changed in the meantime. You have been already waiting for half an hour. Instead you have been able to complete the fields...